# SUM todos los resultados cuando un ID específico está dentro de esos resultados

Tags: mysql, mariadb

A ver si me podeis ayudar con esto. Tengo dos tablas, una es compra y la otra es año (y quizás os preguntais porque narices no pongo el id_año en la primera tabla - el problema real es con tablas distintas y bastante más grandes pero la lógica es la misma):

```
id_compra | id_cliente | precio
1            1            20
2            2            40
3            3            30
4            4            5
5            1            10
6            3            80


id_compra | id_año
1            1
2            1
3            2
4            3
5            4
6            4
```

Bien, lo que quiero hacer es sacar los datos totales de un año solamente cuando el cliente que selecciono ha comprado en ese año. En el caso del cliente número 1, debería sacar los totales del año 1 y del año 4, tal que así:

```
id_año | SUM(price)
1        60
4        90
```

Tengo este MySQL:

```
SELECT e.id_año, SUM(b.precio) FROM compra as b INNER JOIN año as e ON (e.id_compra=b.id_compra)
WHERE e.id_año = (SELECT id_año FROM año INNER JOIN compra ON (año.id_compra=compra.id_compra) WHERE
compra.id_cliente = 1 LIMIT 1) GROUP BY e.id_año
```

Pero no funciona, entiendo yo porque solo lee una vez la subconsulta (pero si no pongo el LIMIT 1 no saca nada). ¿Hay alguna manera de hacerlo "iterativo"?

Perdonadme si soy un poco noob en MySQL pero a veces me vuelvo loco para sacar lo que a priori parecen tonterias.

Muchas gracias por la ayuda!

Un saludo.

Comment: En el ejemplo del cliente 1 de dónde salen los totales 60  y 90 para el año 1 y 4?

Comment: Año 1 supone las compras id 1 y 2 (20+40), año 4 supone las compras 5 y 6 (10+80)

Comment: Segun veo creo que bastaria con `SELECT e.id_año, SUM(b.precio) FROM compra as b INNER JOIN año as e ON (e.id_compra=b.id_compra)
) GROUP BY e.id_año` sin la parte del WHERE

Comment: No, eso me daría los totales de todos los años, quiero los totales de los años en los que el cliente ID 1 ha hecho una compra

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La consulta quedaría así:

```
select id_año , SUM(precio)
from año
where id_año in 
(
   -- extraer los años en los que ha comprado el cliente 1
   -- y usarlo como filtro en el where
   select id_año from
   compra as c join año as a on c.id_compra = a.id_compra
   where c.id_cliente = 1
)
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias! Sabía yo que iba a ser una tontería y efectivamente, tan simple como cambiar el = por el IN...